# How to change the hitbox's shape of a image in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, phaser-framework, matter.js

I am creating a skateboarding game in JavaScript using the Phaser 3 framework. I have loaded the ramp image onto the screen, and I am currently using the "arcade" physics engine in my file. I know I have to use the matter physics engine to have a non-rectangular hitbox. How do I implement it with the triangular hitbox?

I have the .png image file of the ramp, along with the .json file for its hitbox.

I tried following a tutorial off of a website on how to create new hitboxes for the matter physics engine. Everything ended up falling off the screen and I couldn't figure out how to use the .json file for the ramp.

```
//Configurations for the physics engine
var physicsConfig = {
    default: 'arcade',
    arcade : {
        debug : true  //CHANGE THIS TO TRUE TO SEE LINES
    }
}

//Game configurations
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 1200 ,
    height: 600,
    physics: physicsConfig,
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update
    }   
}

//Start the game
var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload() {
    //Images
    this.load.image('sky', 'archery_assets/images/sky.png');
    this.load.image('ground', 'skate_assets/images/ground.png');
    this.load.image('up_ramp', 'skate_assets/images/up_ramp.png')

    //Spritesheets
    this.load.spritesheet('player', 'skate_assets/spritesheets/skater.png', {frameWidth: 160, frameHeight: 160});

}

function create() {
    //Background
    skyImg = this.add.image(600, 300, 'sky');
    //Scale the images
    skyImg.setDisplaySize(1200, 600);
    groundImg = this.add.image(600, 600, 'ground');
    groundImg.setDisplaySize(1200, 250);

    //Create the player
    this.player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 410, 'player');
    this.player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);

    //Rolling animation 
    this.anims.create({
        key: 'move',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('player', {start: 0, end: 3}),
        frameRate: 16,
        repeat: -1 // <-- keeps the rolling animation going
    });
    //Pushing animation
    this.anims.create({
        key: 'push',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('player', {start: 4, end: 8}),
        frameRate: 16
    });
    //Start and keep the rolling animation going
    this.player.anims.play('move', true);

    //Up ramp (1st ramp)
    this.upRamp = this.physics.add.sprite(700, 330, 'up_ramp');
    this.upRamp.setSize(320, 150).setOffset(0, 175);
    this.upRamp.enableBody = true;
    this.upRamp.setImmovable();
    this.upRamp.body.angle = 150;

    //Input
    this.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

    //Spacebar
    this.spacebar = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.SPACE);

    this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.upRamp);
}


function update() {

    //Set variable for push speed
    var playerPushSpeed = 0;

    //If the spacebar is pressed 
    if (this.spacebar.isDown) {
        //Play the push animation
        this.player.anims.play('push', true);

        //Push speed
        playerPushSpeed += 175;

        //Move player
        this.player.setVelocityX(playerPushSpeed);   
    }

    if (this.upRamp.body.touching.left) {
        this.player.setVelocityY(-200);
    }
}
```

I need to know how to implement the .png image of the ramp along with its .json hitbox file, so that the player can properly "ride" up the ramp.

Comment: Could you host the image somewhere so I could access them & recreate this issue?

Comment: @ManuelAbascal https://github.com/roberto257/Olympic-Games. The images and json are under skate_assets

Comment: @ManuelAbascal did the link work okay? Any further questions you need answered to help please ask

Comment: Hi @Robert Smith, I'm at work right now. But I'll take a look later today for sure

Comment: @ManuelAbascal no worries, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use the **`physics: { default: 'matter' }`** in order to change the ***hitbox's shape***. Use this code snippet for reference:

```
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    physics: {
        default: 'matter',
        matter: {
            gravity: {
                y: 0
            },
            debug: true
        }
    },
    scene: {
        create: create
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function create ()
{
    this.matter.world.setBounds();

    this.matter.add.rectangle(200, 200, 200, 200, { 
        chamfer: { radius: [230, 0, 200, 0 ] }
    });

    this.matter.add.mouseSpring();
}
```

You could also use a PhysicsEditor, you can **[check this tutorial](https://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor/tutorials/how-to-create-physics-shapes-for-phaser-3-and-matterjs)** on how to implement different shapes.

**EDIT:**

You can use **`console.log(this.matter.bodies)`** to check other available shapes to implement.

Comment: Thank you. I have been looking at that tutorial trying to implement it. What does the “mouseSpring()” do? And can you implement shapes besides rectangles?

Comment: I have it working now. Only problem is, how do I set the sprites so that they cannot move? For example, in the arcade physics engine, it was "setImmovable()"

Comment: @RobertSmith did you remove the `this.matter.add.mouseSpring();`?

Comment: Yes. Does that prevent the sprites from shaking like hey are currently

Comment: Could you make an edit to your question to include the new issue that you're facing now? Include all the details that you think can help understanding the issue. I'm not quite sure what's the problem currently. I'll take a look tomorrow night or over the weekend for sure. It'll be good open a chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201354/discussion-between-manuel-abascal-and-robert-smith).

Comment: Will do, I will have to recreate it as I scrapped it

Comment: I sent you a message in the chatroom you have posted